# Solr core getting locked intermittenlty

Tags: solr

We are using `SOLR` in `Sitecore 10.2` version. But sometimes `SOLR` core getting locked. After restarting the `SOLR` app service, it is getting up.

Error:

```
sitecore_web_index:     org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Index dir 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_web_index\data\index/' of core 'sitecore_web_index' is already locked. The most likely cause is another Solr server (or another solr core in this server) also configured to use this directory; other possible causes may be specific to lockType: native
```

Comment: @Raman, those are same, but nothing is marked us answer. And also those answer seems additional configuration

Comment: Is it getting locked during indexing? Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444493/caused-by-org-apache-solr-common-solrexception-index-locked-for-write-for-core) and its answers.

Comment: Are you using switch on rebuild? If so, I would take a look at showconfig.aspx and ensure that your indexes are configured to swap to the correct rebuild core. 

i.e. `core > core_rebuild` and not `master/web > core_rebuild`.

Comment: How are you hosting Solr?